# Nested Generic Method in c#

Tags: c#, generics, methods

How can I do this in C#?

```
public bool IsValid<Validator<T>>(T model)
{
  //...
}
```

i want use :

```
IsValid<Validator.City>(city);
```

instead of

```
IsValid<CityViewModel,Validator.City>(city);
```

My function is :

```
public static bool IsValid<TModel, TValidator>(TModel Item) where TValidator : AbstractValidator<TModel>, new()
    {
        var validate = new TValidator();
      //...
    }
```

Comment: have you try to write as is your code in c#?

Comment: You forgot to ask the question.

Comment: You completely changed the content of your post and render all the answers useless. Still it is completely unclear, what you are trying to ask.

Comment: please delete this useless question

Answer (score 3):

You can constrain the generic type argument using `where T : SomeType` in the method's signature.

As a side note: I prefer using type argument names that help understand what types are expected (here: `TValidator` and `TModel`). This makes the code much more readable than using just `T`.

```
public bool IsValid<TValidator>(TModel model) 
    where TValidator : Validator<TModel> 
{
   //return true;     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to enforce the constraint that the generic type should inherit from `Validator` class then you can use below syntax.

```
public bool IsValid<T>(T model) where T : Validator<T>
{
    //return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In C# you do it with a constraint like so:

```
public bool IsValid<T>(T model) where T : Validator<T> 
{
   //return true;     
}
```

Read more about constraints: [Constraints on Type Parameters (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx).